# How to calculate the average of a sequence of integer numbers read from the console?

Tags: java, eclipse, average

What is missing in my code in order to calculate the average of the inputted numbers from the user?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    float average;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your number is " + n);
    } while (n != 0);

    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println("The average is : " + n);
    }

    scanner.close();
}

}
```

When the user puts in "0" then the programm should calculate the average of the inputted numbers by the user, that is why i wrote "while (n != 0)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually using the numbers that you are reading in. A good editor would tell you that before you even ran it. I would look into getting the [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) IDE. You will want to do something similar to that suggested by [jhenrique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303220/jhenrique). I would say it is probably better to add the numbers as integers and then cast later, so that you do not lose accuracy on floating point additions, which can cause you a lot of grief in some cases (but here you are probably fine). Here is my suggested code, modified from jhenrique's answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your number is " + n);

        sum += n;
        count++;
    } while (n != 0);

    System.out.println("The average is : " + ((double) sum) / (count - 1));

    scanner.close();
}
```

`double` is like `float`, but more accurate. In the loop, I add each read number to `sum` and then divide by the number of things read at the end to get the average.

Comment: yes i see, both of your codes work fine, but yours is a little bit easier to understand! anyways, i thank you for your help and good explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:
Note that as you have one more number (the zero), then you have to consider it when calculating the average by removing it, because you ask for 0 to finish the program.

public class Teste {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    double average = 0;
    int qtdNums = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your number is " + n);

        average = average + n;
        qtdNums++;
    } while (n != 0);

    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println("The average is : " + average / (qtdNums - 1));
    }

    scanner.close();
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for you help, it works fine! but i dont understand quite why qtdNums - 1? is that 0 - 1 ? and the part with qtdNums++. Could you explain me that quickly please :) ?

Comment: You are considering all numbers to the average. Lets say the user inforns 5 numbers plus the 0 to stop, then you have 6 total, but you want just 5 to calculate the average. Thats why you have to remove 1

Comment: @Larry See my derived answer (I gave jhenrique credit)